# Square root in html

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to make a square root bar in html in the script part? I found this

https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/7k3sL1jf/

the 2nd one works great but i want it inside a script
my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/sxaz9g34/4/

code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

  document.write("y = &#177; &#8730; 16-x"+"2".sup()+"<br>");
  &radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">4</span>

  document.write("");
</script>
Square Root
</body>
</html>
```

I expect when the program to run for the 4 to be under a square root sin. But the actual results im not getting this. Can't figure out how to put this html span tag i found to work in a document.write.

Comment: i tried that  https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/sxaz9g34/42/    one of the first things i tried

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/sxaz9g34/115/   im trying to add x to the 2nd to it but cant get it to work correctly    .sup() after 2 in my comments makes it

Comment: I got it ty for the help . all these answers are very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

  document.write("y = &#177; &radic; <span style='border-top:1px solid black'>16-x"+"2".sup()+"</span><br /><br/> &radic;<span style='border-top:1px solid black'>4</span>");


  document.write("");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: pretty much thanks that bar is kind of messed up tho im working on the format https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/sxaz9g34/115/

Answer (score 2):

You would most likely want something like this:

```js
function writeSquareRoot(num) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">' + num + '</span>';
}


writeSquareRoot(1);
writeSquareRoot(5);
writeSquareRoot(10);
writeSquareRoot(15);
writeSquareRoot(20);
```

#### What's Happening

`writeSquareRoot` is appending the formatted HTML to the end of the body.

---

### Improvements

#### Using an ID and manually adding

Some improvements to this would be to add in an `id` parameter and 
corresponding elements so that we aren't appending directly to the body, but rather, a very specific place:

```js
function writeSquareRoot(num, elId) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elId);
  el.innerHTML += '&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">' + num + '</span>';
}


writeSquareRoot(1, 'sq-one');
writeSquareRoot(5, 'sq-five');
writeSquareRoot(10, 'sq-ten');
writeSquareRoot(15, 'sq-fifteen');
writeSquareRoot(20, 'sq-twenty');
```

```html
<div id="sq-one"></div>
<div id="sq-five"></div>
<div id="sq-ten"></div>
<div id="sq-fifteen"></div>
<div id="sq-twenty"></div>
```

#### Arrow fn to be called anywhere you want that returns the value

```js
var sqrDraw = n => '&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">' + n + '</span>'


document.write("x"+"2".sup()+" + "+"y"+"2".sup()+" = 16 ");
document.write("A = (2x)(2y) = 4xy <br>");
document.write("y = &#177; " + sqrDraw(16) + "-x"+"2".sup()+"<br>");
```

Comment: is there a way to do it not in a function? i tried adding just the bit under the function and replacing num with a random number and it didnt work

Comment: thanks for the help this is all very interesting. really cool what u can do with html/js

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually used

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>

  document.write("y = &#177;"+'&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">16-x<sup>2</sup></span>'+"<br>");
  
  
  //&#8730; 16-x"+"2".sup()
  //
  
</script>
Square Root
</body>
</html>
```

other then the 2 colliding with the top this is a very good way to make a square root on a html page.